# how to remove delay when looping a playlist in jPlayer?

Tags: audio, loops, jplayer

i have the loop playlist functionality working well with:

```
{
swfPath: "js",
supplied: "oga, mp3",
wmode: "window",
loop: "true",
});
```

however there is a few seconds gap between when the playlist finishes and then starts again.

the playlist only contains one file and so i am going for a 'seamless' sound effect but at the moment there is a gap between when the playlist ends and then starts again.

does anyone know if there is an option to remove this gap or somehow manage it so that it appears to have no gap?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

from the developer:

"Well, if you are only playing 1 piece of media, using the playlist is a verbose way of doing it... Introducing a number of effects that would not normally be there. The delay is due to the playlist assuming that the next track is different to the previous track... So it always sets the media again each time and this will be the source of the delay.

Do it more like a single player and the delay will be much smaller. There will always be a small delay, but much better than you are experiencing.

For example, this demo here is better suited:
http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01/"